# Lambda invocation from AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I want to create an trigger which  invoke the lambda function when there in any event(Insert, Update etc) in the RDS database table like in dynamoDB(For any database engine).
And also want to create this Lambda dynamically in Node js.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only supported only with AWS RDS Aurora Database. Check the article [Capturing Data Changes in Amazon Aurora Using AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/capturing-data-changes-in-amazon-aurora-using-aws-lambda/) in AWS Database blog for an example use case.

You can Dynamically Create the Lambda function and Update the Aurora Stored Procedure with a Query to trigger the created Lambda function.